# What is the maximum number of vertices for polygons & polylines in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

What is the maximum number of vertices for polygons and polylines (including multipart) in PostGIS?

Comment: I believe it is a setting somewhere, Oracle spatial I think has a limit of 8999.

Answer (score 10):

The only link I could find about this is [a post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/postgis-users/1jRSuQMacS4/-uSe7AnQm08J) on the discussion group tittled, `What is maximum limit(max number of coordinates) for a LineString?` where it is mentioned that

> It's a 32bit integer, so theoretically you should be able to have up
>   to 4,294,967,295 vertices per line.

**Update**
According to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59249/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-vertices-for-polygons-polylines-in-postgis/59250?noredirect=1#comment79264_59250) comment by [Paul Ramsey](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/457/paul-ramsey), the Number of vertices is lower:

> This is correct, though the npoints counter is a signed integer (oh
>   well), so you can "only" get 2 billion vertices in.

I would believe that the same limit would hold for a polygon.

Your question however raises more questions. What exactly are you trying to do where you would be concerned about the limit of vertices in a polygon? If you are indeed running into this limit, then you are definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: This is correct, though the npoints counter is a signed integer (oh well), so you can "only" get 2 billion vertices in.